# Why is my file not found and therefore will always be recreated?

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system

I want to look for a specific CSV file in my default directory. If the file is found, the deed is done and content should be appended to the file, otherwise, the file should be created.

```
    def set_defaultfile(self):

        file = "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/MindNotez/"
        df_content = {"title": [], "author": [], "year": [], "others": [], "note": []}
        for file in os.listdir(file):
            if file.endswith("Note.csv"):
                file_content = file + "Note.csv"
                return file_content
            else:
                df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_content)
                df.to_csv(file + "Note.csv", sep=",", index=False)
                file_content = file + "Note.csv"
                return file_content
```

I use the return statements so that the variable can be used by other functions. I was looking for a better 'search' function for the file but only found how to look for all files with a certain 'end' (ex. ".txt").

The result of this function is also not the creation of a file named "Note.csv" but the file is always called ".ideaNote.csv". Can somebody explain me what or why that prefix is?

As always, thank you very much for your asnwers!

Best regards,

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a satisfiable solution for it myself.

I use this code instead:

```
    def set_defaultfile(self):

        file = "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/MindNotez/Note.csv"
        df_content = {"title": [], "author": [], "year": [], "others": [], "note": []}
        try:
            with open(file, "r") as test:
                f_reader = csv.DictReader(test, delimiter=',')
                headers = f_reader.fieldnames
                if  headers == df_content:

                print("Headers match!")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File created!")
            with open(file, "a+") as f:
                f_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=df_content)
                f_writer.writeheader()
                f.close()

        file_content = "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/MindNotez/Note.csv"
        return file_content
```

However, **I am still interested why a file with prefix '.idea' is created in my first option**.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the appended **.idea** I am not sure why, but I would guess that the problem is that there is a file or folder called .idea that is taken as the prefix. Let's explain why I think this is what happening. Imagine that there is only a file called **.idea** in the folder, then the for loop will only pass once (as we assumed there are no more elements in the folder) resulting in `file = '.idea'`, so the `if()` fails and it goes to else.

The problem is that because you used the same name for the path and for the element in the loop, Python selects the latter, not the former. Then inside the `else` part, we will have:

```
file_content = file + "Note.csv"
```

and this is equivalent to

```
file_content = ".idea" + "Note.csv"
```

not what you were expecting. To solve it with the old version of the code, use this (I commented out the original lines of code that I modified):

```
# file = "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/MindNotez/"
file_path = "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/MindNotez/"
    df_content = {"title": [], "author": [], "year": [], "others": [], "note": []}
    # for file in os.listdir(file):
    for file in os.listdir(file_path):
        if file.endswith("Note.csv"):
            # file_content = file + "Note.csv"
            file_content = file_path + "Note.csv"
            return file_content
        else:
            df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_content)
            # df.to_csv(file + "Note.csv", sep=",", index=False)
            df.to_csv(file_path + "Note.csv", sep=",", index=False)
            file_content = file + "Note.csv"
            return file_content
```

Try this to see if my guess is correct. I hope this helped to solve the doubt.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I can only see that you basically just changed the name of my file variable. Right? I like your explanation about the '.idea'-prefix. If I could, I would upvote your answer ;)

Comment: Yes, it was just a change of the name to avoid possible collisions of names for different variables. You are welcome :)